# React Native, state changing for all items instead of clicked item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I created a button in flat list, when user click an specific item, it's button should change state and increment button should appear, but button changing state for all the items. I pass id too but it's not working, can someone please help me... below is my code

Items.js

```
<FlatList
              data={this.props.items}
              extraData={this.props}
              keyExtractor={(items) => items.id.toString()}
              numColumns={2}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <CardBuyItem>
                  <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image} />
                  <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.subTitle} numberOfLines={1}>
                      {item.subTitle}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.price}>Rs {item.price}</Text>
                  </View>

                  {this.props.button && this.props.added.length > 0 ? (
                    <View style={styles.add}>
                      <Text style={styles.quantity}>{item.quantity}</Text>
                      <MaterialCommunityIcons
                        style={styles.iconUp}
                        size={20}
                        name="plus-circle-outline"
                        onPress={() => this.props.addQuantity(item.id)}
                      />
                      <MaterialCommunityIcons
                        style={styles.iconDown}
                        size={20}
                        name="minus-circle-outline"
                        onPress={() => this.props.subtractQuantity(item.id)}
                      />
                    </View>
                  ) : (
                    <View style={styles.buy}>
                      <Text
                        style={styles.buyonce}
                        onPress={() => {
                          this.props.addToCart(item.id);
                          this.props.showCart();
                          this.props.showButton(item.id);
                        }}
                      >
                        Buy Once
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  )}
                </CardBuyItem>
              )}
            />
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.clothes.jeans,
    button: state.clothes.showButton,
    added: state.clothes.addedItems,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addToCart: (id) => dispatch(addToCart(id)),
    addQuantity: (id) => dispatch(addQuantity(id)),
    subtractQuantity: (id) => dispatch(subtractQuantity(id)),
    showCart: () => dispatch(showCart()),
    showButton: (id) => dispatch(showButton(id)),
  };
};
```

That's my item list with `mapStateToProsp` and `mapDispatchToProps` here button should change it's state

reducer.js

```
if (action.type === SHOW_BUTTON) {
    let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
    return {
      ...state,
      addedItem: addedItem,
      showButton: action.showButton,
    };
}

const initialstate = {  showButton: false}
```

it's my reducer function with initial state of that button

action.js

```
export const showButton = (id) => {
  return {
    type: SHOW_BUTTON,
    showButton: true,
    id,
  };
};
```

it's my action where I'm describing action for my reducer

Comment: You are having a common prop to showButton move it to item level, whats the logic to show the button ?

Comment: common prop to showButton? sorry didn't get you, the logic is that to let user know item is added to cart

Comment: you only have one showButton in your state so its common, once you enable it the button will show

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: you could have a flag in items of state.jeans and update that

Comment: so i need move show button to jeans array?

Comment: Yes items of that should have a property like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223201/discussion-between-kanwarjeet-singh-and-guruparan-giritharan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a common state variable for this which causes it to show all buttons.

You can do a simple solution like this.
In your flatlist you can have a logic to display the button

```
{this.props.added.find(x=>x.id==item.id) !=null ? (
```

Or if you have to use the reducer, you will have to have a property in the array and update it which would be complex to maintain.